# How to fetch data using RestTemplate in Spring

Tags: json, resttemplate, spring-web

My task is writting a code to fetch data from rest API via URL like this

```
curl -k -v -XPOST -H "username: password" -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:8181/api/rest/person/query -d '
    {
        "name": "person's name",
        "role": "role code",
        "programme": "programme code"
    }'
```

And here's my code

```
   public JsonUser fetchJsonUserByName(String name) throws IOException{
       String jsonName = "'{'name': "+"'"+name+"'}'";
       String url = "/person/query -d "+jsonName;
       ResponseEntity<JsonUser> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, JsonUser.class);
           try {
            if(response.hasBody()) return response.getBody();
               else return null;
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            if(e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) return null;
            throw new IOException("error fetching user", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("error fetching user", e);
        }
   }
```

And I got the error code 500 when I run my code, where was I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this there is nothing about [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) in this question. Please, be careful with tags selection in the future.

Your mistake here that you are missing the part that you use `POST` HTTP method with the curl. But with the `RestRemplate` you choose `GET`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve an entity by doing a GET on the specified URL.
 * The response is converted and stored in an {@link ResponseEntity}.
 * <p>URI Template variables are expanded using the given URI variables, if any.
 * @param url the URL
 * @param responseType the type of the return value
 * @param uriVariables the variables to expand the template
 * @return the entity
 * @since 3.0.2
 */
<T> ResponseEntity<T> getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException;
```

Somehow I guess you meant this:

```
/**
 * Create a new resource by POSTing the given object to the URI template,
 * and returns the response as {@link ResponseEntity}.
 * <p>URI Template variables are expanded using the given URI variables, if any.
 * <p>The {@code request} parameter can be a {@link HttpEntity} in order to
 * add additional HTTP headers to the request.
 * @param url the URL
 * @param request the Object to be POSTed (may be {@code null})
 * @param uriVariables the variables to expand the template
 * @return the converted object
 * @since 3.0.2
 * @see HttpEntity
 */
<T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
        throws RestClientException;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will be careful in next questions.

Comment: Btw, `-d` is curl option. In case of post via `RestTemplate` you have to move your `jsonName` into that `request` argument . Right now your URL isn't correct

Comment: Thanks again for your useful infomation. I also guess the reason about my URL.

Comment: Is it right?!
ResponseEntity<JsonUser> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,JsonUser.class,responseType,jsonName);

Comment: No, your `jsonName` is request body, not paeans. Please read about HTTP protocol more

Comment: Right! i'm so noob bro. Post method retrieve data from "back-end", not via URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135622/discussion-between-thnh-ku-and-artem-bilan).

Answer (score 1):

Please confer to [HTTP response codes, explained](https://paulmurraywork.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/http-response-codes-explained/), where you will see that 500 means “I fucked up”, and that is the server’s point of view. It’s a server error, not yours.

Of course, the server error may be caused by malformed input such as you sending the totally wrong URL `/person/query -d '{'name': 'name'}'`.

Comment: I've tested manually by using command in Terminal and server still worked correctly with this input type '{'name': 'name'}' . So difficult to understand why code not working.

Comment: The problem is not that it is the wrong parameter, but that you put it in the URL instead of the body. The other answer made that sufficiently clear.